# How to work with output stream while using dotnet cli?

Tags: c#, .net-core, dotnet-cli

I've been trying to use simple line:

```
Console.Write(new string('=', Console.WindowWidth));
```

It's being invoked through `dotnet test`. Guess, this issue is described 
[here](https://github.com/dotnet/cli/issues/2780)

Brief stacktrace:

```
System.IO.IOException: The handle is invalid
   at System.ConsolePal.GetBufferInfo(Boolean throwOnNoConsole, Boolean& succeeded)
   at System.ConsolePal.get_WindowWidth()
   at System.Console.get_WindowWidth()
```

Any workaround before RTM release?

Comment: Which version of `dotnet` are you using? Your code seems to run fine on 1.0.0-preview2-003121

Comment: @HenrikIlgen: `1.0.0-preview2-003131`

Comment: Well, if you are running it through simply `dotnet run`, it will work. It fails with `dotnet test` execution flow (It's part from my custom simplistic test adapter)

Comment: which test runner are you using? xunit? if so, you could also file an issue on its repo.

Comment: @MartinUllrich my own custom simplistic one. It figured out, thet stdout redirect is not completely supported yet, but likely planned for RTM